# MVC ViewModel EntityFrameWork ICollection,IEnumerable virtual Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have gone through a lot of documents and found several ways of trying to make a CreateViewModel.

I want to know what does ICollection Does.

```
public Payment{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string Details {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Expense> Expenses {get; set;}


}

public Expense{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string MyDetails {get; set;}

}
```

So I guess in my View, I can Use just the plain class as virtual to make a Create Method. But if I want to use ViewModel to make a view with 2 or more DataModels for Creation. How will I go with that. Cause I guess I can always just make a

```
public virtual Payment payments {get; set;}
public virtual Expense expenses {get; set;}
```

But I am trying to ready this for Dynamically Having a Add Button Generating an Expense Details Input.

Not to mention, the IEnumerable as well, but I guess this needs an ID more suitable for Editing and Details for what I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is a `PaymentViewModel` class, where you'll use `List<Expense>` instead of `ICollection<Expense>`:

```
public class PaymentViewModel
{
    // ID property unnecessary here because it doesn't need
    // to be posted from the form

    public string Details { get; set; }

    // You may want to use something like `List<ExpenseViewModel>`
    // based on your needs
    public List<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
}
```

With that, you add additional expense records to your form by making sure the input names are in the format of `Expenses[N].MyDetails`, where `N` is the index. Whatever JavaScript solution you use to add additional expense records to the form should create these inputs with properly indexed names. This would be a good place to use a JavaScript templating solution, or something that handles data-binding like Knockout.

For editing existing expenses, should you have the need, you just generate the fields like with any collection, but you need to use a `for` loop rather than the more traditional `foreach`:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Expenses.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Expenses[i].MyDetails)
}
```

As a side note, since you asked, `ICollection<T>` is the required type for entity navigation properties with Entity Framework. These reasons are very low level, but has to do with the way Entity Framework handles one-to-many and many-to-many relationships at an object level and issues such as lazy loading. However, `ICollection<T>` doesn't work for actually submitting items through an HTML form, due mostly to the fact that it's not indexable. That's why a view model is so important in this scenario.

Comment: Omg, makes perfect sense. Thank you!!